# EXCEL VBA , Search Line Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to run an excel vba form to search through the lines, but for some unknown reason I get the error:

> Method Range of object Global failed

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim last, i As Integer
    Dim ref, lote As String
    'Sheets("analisegeral").Visible = True
    Sheets("analisegeral").Select
    last = Range("analisegeral").End(xlUp).Row + 1  

       For i = 2 To last                         ref = Cells(i, 8)
          lote = Cells(i, 13)

          If TextBox1.Text = ref Then
             TextBox2.Text = lote
             GoTo fim
          End If

       Next i

       If TextBox1.Text <> ref Then
          TextBox2.Text = ""
          MsgBox "Referência não encontrada!", vbInformation
          TextBox1.Text = ""
          TextBox2.Text = ""
          GoTo fim
       End If
    fim:
End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying the range with a workbook and worksheet name before the `Range("analisegeral").end...` line -- assuming there is a named range by that name (are you sure there is? Double check). Also, it seems like you were trying to `activate` the worksheet, but I could be wrong.

Comment: `ref = Cells(i, 8)` is on the same line as `For i = 2 To last `. Is it intentional? If so, separate these two statements with `:` or move `ref = Cells(i, 8)` to another line. Also, you can't select range if you you're not on the sheet where the range is located.

Comment: I gather that the analisegeral worksheet is **not** the one with the button or the one whose private worksheet code sheet that private sub is in.

Comment: Please confirm that you have a named range called *analisegeral* on the *analisegeral* worksheet.

Comment: @AntiDrondert It's not on the same line , only on stackoverflow... And i have a `Sheet("...").Select`

Comment: @Jeeped Can you be more specific?

Comment: No. I was perfectly specific and my inquiries require lucid responses, not vague requests for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are few issues with your code.

#### Invalid declaration

```
Dim last, i As Integer
Dim ref, lote As String
```

Note that `last` and `ref` are declared as `Variant` type here, unless it was your intent, change it to following:

```
Dim last As Integer, i As Integer
Dim ref As String, lote As String
```

#### Failing to activate worksheet where range is located

```
'Sheets("analisegeral").Visible = True
Sheets("analisegeral").Select
```

The fact that your sheet is hidden (or very hidden) disallows it's selection.
Probably this is the case of your error.

#### Wrong method of calculating last row number

```
last = Range("analisegeral").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Given you will actualy select **analisegeral** sheet, this still doesn't make sense:
`Range("NamedRange")` is a construction that allows to refer to previously named range (either with VBA or manualy). Unless you have one, this will raise another error. Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This will give you a number of **column A** last row.

#### Final advice: [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Hi , i got it working but i was wondering if it was possible to return more than one value and show it as a list on textbox?

Comment: As a string with delimiter? Otherwise it won't be a TextBox but a ListBox.

Comment: I'ts going to be a combobox , but i want to list all the matching values if possible

Comment: I advise you to look into [Validation object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/validation-object-excel), it might be a bit easier to manipulate with than TextBoxes, ComboBoxes or ListBoxes. You can dynamically add matching values to either [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/collection-object) or [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object) in your `else` clause.

Comment: I know i just want to know the code to show not only the first matching line but also the other lines

Comment: @PedroGaspar You can always start a separate question, that is how SO works anyway. It is considered a bad tone to a) answer the question in comments b) make follow-up questions through editing original question or comments. You can be lucky enough to find out that there might be already similiar asked question with an accepted answer.